Why did God form adam only male if He already created them both male and female?
In Gen 1.27 we read:

"וַיִּבְרָא אֱלֹהִים אֶת־הָאָדָם בְּצַלְמוֹ בְּצֶלֶם אֱלֹהִים בָּרָא אֹתוֹ זָכָר וּנְקֵבָה בָּרָא אֹתָם׃"
Lit: "And God created the adam in His image, in the image of Elohim [He] created him, male and female created them."

Note that the use of the definite article ה points to the fact that "adam" is a noun, not a name, so I keep using it that way. We also distinguish between the stage of creation (ברא) and formation (יצר).
We would assume, that the later formation of the adam should also be male and female. Indeed, nothing in the latter verse (Gen 2.7) indicates that the adam was formed  male, as male gender is used in Hebrew also as neutral (like "a child"). We only realize that later in the narrative:

"וַיִּיצֶר י"א אֶת־הָאָדָם עָפָר מִן־הָאֲדָמָה וַיִּפַּח בְּאַפָּיו נִשְׁמַת חַיִּים וַיְהִי הָאָדָם לְנֶפֶשׁ חַיָּה׃"
Lit: "And Y"E formed the adam (noun) humus from the soil, and blew into his nostrils the breath of life: and the adam became a living soul".


"וַיֹּאמֶר יְהוָה אֱלֹהִים לֹא־טוֹב הֱיוֹת הָאָדָם לְבַדּוֹ אֶעֱשֶׂהּ־לּוֹ עֵזֶר כְּנֶגְדּוֹ׃"
"And Y"E said, “It is not good for the adam to be alone; I will make a fitting counterpart for him.”

Since God already created them male and female, why did He form the adam only [imperfectly] male?
Also, knowing that he was imperfect, why did He wonder “It is not good for the Human to be alone; I will make a fitting counterpart for him.” and tried several experiments to find a cure?

Part of the general trend of Genesis Ch. 1 and Genesis Ch. 2 having different focuses. First Chapter 1 gives us the bigger view -- "God made humans as part of every thing else in creation." Then Chapter 2 rewinds, zooms in, and tells us the "how."

@Shalom Was this big good made of many many small bads? God was really angry at the end of Gen 3. It doesn't connect with your idea.

It's a part of the general trend of Genesis Ch. 1 and Genesis Ch. 2 having different focuses. First Chapter 1 gives us the bigger view -- "God made humans as part of every thing else in creation." Then Chapter 2 rewinds, zooms in, and tells us the "how."

I think the answer is given by Marina Goodman in "Why Should I Stand Behind the Mechitzah if I Could Be a Prayer Leader?", pp. 49-50:

Originally G-d created Adam who was both male and female. However, the female was completely subsumed in male. (YDJ: we see that that G-d refers to Adam - he in the singular). The female in the male-female had no identity, and as a result the male was alone. ... this was an important intermediary state. However, G-d stated that "It is not good, Adam being alone" (Bereshis 2:18). G-d then proceeded to separate out the female and give her her own identity and her own perspective. The male was no longer alone but in a relationship. The female was still in a relationship, but now had a distinct voice.

In other words - as a male, Adam remained, where he was. He was already fit for the job. G-d separated the part that needed development which could not have it otherwise. Sefer Zikaron on Brachos 61a says on Rashi's Bereshis 2:21 comment:

As Rashi has stated, the woman was not created through a removal of internal organ from man. (i.e. no diminishmement of man occured). She was created by separating the female form from the male form of the original dual body... There only remained a wound that needed to be healed.


Thank you. 1. looks like an unsubstantiated comment to me 2. I'm sure we can write hundreds of Droshos on this issue, but the text doesn't seem to be aware of a problem. Reminds me of Jordan Peterson’s musings on Genesis. 3. see 1.

@AlBerko We have to give our answers sometimes too. What was the purpose of the answers in gemara if they could use answers from the prophets? There is another set of drashos from R. Eisenman in a similar direction. https://www.amazon.com/Beginnings-study-topics-Parashas-Bereishis/dp/B0006S2IBA/ref=sr_1_18?dib=eyJ2IjoiMSJ9.CixElxW7fCXIorThCpSURgn8cy9Xt3xg1aGupXZnmwo._m8KITDeTJ5Mi14rC2BwngjM-p1CNMdXy_KnwY3MJ5E&dib_tag=se&qid=1726418266&refinements=p_27%3AM.+Eisemann%5CcMoshe&s=books&sr=1-18&text=M.+Eisemann%2C+Moshe

Oh, I love your answers when you put effort. But sometimes it looks like your batteries are drained and you write short notes that I'm unable to process. IMU, that's the difference between answers and comments.

@AlBerko sorry I misunderstood your question completely. Here's the edit, Marina Goodman is the answer!

I think many will find your answer useful and creative. For my type of mind, "as a male, Adam remained, where he was" is still undecipherable. Let's contemplate interpretative/apologetic (what people seek) vs explanatory (what I aim). The former seeks harmonization of "all known phenomena", i.e. the existing texts - how that part can be reconciled with the rest into a whole. Your excerpt does not take Gen 1 into account at all.

@AlBerko Male and female is from Genesis 1. What did the male part of Adam lose as a result of separation? Wasn't creation of female like giving birth for women?

Can you please present a coherent story from Gen 1 to Gen 2 about Adam's creation and development? Start with וַיִּבְרָא אֱלֹהִים  אֶת־הָאָדָם בְּצַלְמוֹ בְּצֶלֶם אֱלֹהִים בָּרָא אֹתוֹ זָכָר וּנְקֵבָה בָּרָא אֹתָם׃ and end with וַיִּבֶן יְהוָה אֱלֹהִים  אֶת־הַצֵּלָע אֲשֶׁר־לָקַח מִן־הָאָדָם לְאִשָּׁה וַיְבִאֶהָ אֶל־הָאָדָם׃

@AlBerko i did. It follows fine. The only claim one can make that 1:27 speaks of male and female as אתם. Therefore,  if female is underdeveloped, there is no אתם, and he is singular.

The Or HaChaim—حاييم بن موشي بن عطار, חיים בן משה בן עטר, lived in Morocco around 400 years ago.
He notes that in Bereishit 1:27, the Torah says that G-d created Man male and female. However, in 2:18, G-d says, “it is not good for him to be alone.”
How is this possible? The Or HaChaim adds that in 1:28, G-d gives Man the command to be fruitful and multiply, at a time when the Torah has not yet mentioned the existence of Woman as a separate entity. We may have to rely on the explanation of Rabbi Yirmeya ben Elazar in the Babylonian Talmud, Berachot 61a, he concludes.
According to Rabbi Yirmeya ben Elazar, G-d initially created Adam with two faces, each facing a different direction, with the capacity to reproduce independently.
In 2:21, G-d makes the two-faced Adam fall unconscious and takes “מצלעתיו”, closing over the flesh. Rabbi Shraga Silverstein translates מצלעתיו as “sides,” which is consistent with the Talmud, indicating that this primordial surgery removed the male half of Adam from the female half.
Aside from addressing the two-faced Adam’s loneliness, what was the purpose of this surgery?
In 2:18, G-d says, “I shall make a helpmate for him.” However, “for him” is the word כנגדו, which also means “against” or “facing” him. It can also mean opposite, against, before, in view, in sight of, conspicuous to, in the presence of, parallel to, from before, open to, known to, etc.
Holding a person accountable is a necessary part of any relationship. If we accept the interpretation of Rabbi Yirmeya ben Elazar, the two-faced Adam would not be able to do so insofar as it requires “facing” a person. The two-faced Adam didn’t have a contemporary to hold him accountable.
Rabbi Silverstein brings this translation:
“I shall make him a help [(If he merits it, she is a help)], against him [(If he does not merit it, she is against him, contending with him)].”
The Or HaChaim also shows that immediately after this verse, the Torah describes the animals, as if to suggest that they did not merit to be Adam’s partner.
Mekoros:

Or HaChaim:
ויאמר ה' וגו' לא טוב וגו'. קשה הלא כבר ביום ברא אלהים אדם זכר ונקבה
ברא אותם, עוד קשה אומרו סמוך לו אעשה לו עזר כנגדו וגומר ויצר וגומר כל
חית השדה, שנראה שרצה לזווג לו חית השדה וזה פלא לזווג אדם ובהמה, ועוד
שיסיר נקבת בהמה או חיה מבן זוגה ולזווגה עם האדם, עליונים למטה ותחתונים
למעלה, עוד קשה אומרו ויפל ה' תרדמה וגו', וכי לא היה ה' יכול לברוא לו
בת זוגו עפר מן האדמה. מלבד מה שהקשינו שמצינו לו שברא לו בת זוגו ביום
הבראו וכמו שהעיד הכתוב אחר כן זכר ונקבה בראם וגו' ביום הבראם ורז"ל
אמרו דרשות רבות וצריכין פותר אבל פשט הכתוב לא מצאנוהו: ויאמר השם
אלוקים לא טוב.
The Lord G'd said: "It is not good for man to be alone, etc." This is
difficult since G'd had mentioned already on the day He created man
that the species had been created male and female (1,27). Another
problem in the text is the expression אעשה, "I shall make for him a
helpmate." The Torah then immediately proceeds to describe that the
mammals and the birds were formed, i.e. ויצר השם אלוקים (2,19). This
gives the impression that G'd intended one of these animals to be
man's helpmate. Such a thought is not only extremely strange, but if
true it would also result in one of those animals being deprived of
its own mate! Besides, why did G'd have to put Adam to sleep and to
remove part of his body? Could He not have formed woman as dust from
the earth as He had formed man himself, especially since He formed Eve
on the very same day He formed Adam (5,2) זכר ונקבה בראם? Our sages
have given many homiletical explanations in answer to these questions,
but they have not provided us with פשט, straightforward answers that
justify the text as it stands.
Or HaChaim:
ונראה לפי מה שקדם מדברי רז"ל (עירובין יח) כי אדם וחוה דו פרצופין נבראו
למאן דאמר פרצוף, ולמאן דאמר זנב, כדאיתא במס' שבת, וכפי זה זאת האשה וזה
בניינה כי מתחלה בראה דבוקה עמו ממש למ"ד כסברתו ולמ"ד כסברתו. ובסדר זה
ישנם גם כן בהכנת המוליד דהלא תמצא שאמר ה' להם (א' כח) פרו ורבו וגו'
קודם הנסירה הא למדת שהכינם ה' להוליד גם בהיותם בסדר זה וזאת האשה אשר
נסר ה' ולקחה ממקום דביקתה אשר בראה ביום הבראם.
We may have to fall back on the opinions expressed in Berachot 61 that
originally man was created with two faces in one body. The Talmud
there offers two opinions as to what was removed from Adam, a tail or
a face, respectively. This is a reasonable explanation because it
justifies G'd's blessing or command to Adam to be fruitful and to
multiply (1,28) at a time when woman had not yet been reported as a
separate entity.
Brachot 61a:
אִי נָמֵי כִּדְרַבִּי יִרְמְיָה בֶּן אֶלְעָזָר. דְּאָמַר רַבִּי
יִרְמְיָה בֶּן אֶלְעָזָר: דּוּ פַּרְצוּפִין בָּרָא הַקָּדוֹשׁ בָּרוּךְ
הוּא בָּאָדָם הָרִאשׁוֹן, שֶׁנֶּאֱמַר: ״אָחוֹר וָקֶדֶם צַרְתָּנִי״.
Alternatively, this duplication in the language of creation can be
explained in accordance with the statement of Rabbi Yirmeya ben
Elazar, as Rabbi Yirmeya ben Elazar said: The Holy One, Blessed be He,
created two faces [du partzufin] on Adam the first man; he was created
both male and female in a single body, as it is stated: “You have
formed me [tzartani] behind and before” (Psalms 139:5); tzartani is
derived from the word tzura [face]. God formed two faces on a single
creation, back and front.

